# Prove that $G/N = \{1N\}$ iff $G=N$

Tags: group-theory

Prove that $G/N = \{1N\}$ iff $G=N$

Where $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, a finite group.

I'm having trouble proving this. Could someone please help me? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? One direction should be pretty easy, and the difficulty of the other depends on what material you've covered, so some extra context would be helpful

Comment: So far, I have tried expressing an element of G as a product of elements of N by equating the cosets of N in G but I was never able to get any results. I've covered material up to the Isomorphism theorems.

Comment: If $G/N = \{eN\}$ then $N$ has only one coset in $G$.

Answer (score 1):

On the non-trivial direction, if $G/N=\{eN\}$ then for any $g \in G$: $gN=eN$. So $gN \subseteq eN$. Remember $gN = \{g\cdot n\ | n\in N\}$. Therefore $g=g \cdot e \in gN \subseteq eN$.

Meaning, there exists some $n \in N$ s.t. $g = e n$, therefore $g = n$. What could you then say about $g$, and thus on the relation between $G$ and $N$?